# Maven for resolving dependencies with cloud APIs

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm very new to Maven, in fact I installed it and tried to compile my first pom file with a few dependencies just mere hours ago.

I'm trying to built a rest web service in Java that communicates with Eucalyptus and OpenStack, using amazonaws and openstack4j respectively. However, I've run into some problems compiling these two together, seeing as they are dependent on many other jars as well, version specific and so on.

I tried adding the dependency for openstack4j and amazonaws (I assume I need to add the one for jersey as well), but when it gets compiled, the downloaded jars were stored in the repository folder for maven. Do I need to go collect each and every one of them by hand so I can add them to my Eclipse project as an External jar?

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without any more details about your pom, project, and setup. There are a couple of things you can try to do.

1. Make sure you have [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) installed in your eclipse. This will help eclipse auto download the required dependencies.
2. Make sure your project is set up as a maven project. If already imported into maven you can `Right click on project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project`. If it's not open in eclipse `File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects`.

Once you have all of that set up, you should be able to `right click project > Maven > *Maven Options for Downloading Sources, Updating project, etc.*`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this question. I've installed m2e as well and I've tried to set up a maven project just to test things out. Basically I need the API for Eucalyptus, OpenStack and I need jersey for the rest web service. However, I'm not sure which versions to add to these dependencies. Is this something I have to look up, or Maven takes care of?

I've managed to add the dependencies, but the exceptions I'm getting suggest they weren't the right ones...

Comment: You'll have to figure out which dependencies and which versions of those you'll need. Maven will only take care of actually downloading them for you. You can check out a site like [mvn repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for dependency information. Please share the exceptions if you need help resolving them.

Comment: I took care of this yesterday, but your answer is correct, so thank you for it. :)